# C# fetch textbox with variable in name

Tags: c#, textbox, controls, fetch, visual-studio-2019

i have 8 textboxes in my code that are visible =false.
Now i want to set them visible after a button click event.

The textbox names are:

tb1
tb2
tb3
...

I want fetch the textbox with tb+i (i=1) and make them visible.
After the first textbox is visible, there is an i++, so every click just show one textbox more.

I already tried that, but it didnt worked:

```
 TextBox textbox = (TextBox)Controls.Find(string.Format("tb"+i), false).FirstOrDefault();

        textbox.Visible = true; */
        i++;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this WinForms?

Comment: Add them on a List and fetch them by their index

Comment: Yes, in WinForms. How do i add them in a List? The Textboxes are on the windows form and not visible.

Comment: Simply do it: yourList.Add(someTextbox); Note that the Name property is not guaranteed to be unique or even set.. Often one uses a Dictionary<string, TextBox> to access them by a name..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i have the solution:

```
 if (i < 9) { var textbox = Controls.Find("tb" + i, true).FirstOrDefault(); if (textbox != null) { textbox.Visible = true; } i++; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try the following

```
//I added the if loop so that you can not go higher then what you have said
            if (i < 9)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.Controls["tb" + i];
                tb.Visible = true;
            }
```

Comment: check the value you had for i, you will have to start it at 1. When you start it at 0 it will look for "tb0" and this is probably not in your form

Comment: that means that your textbox is not called "tb1" make sure that everything is identical else it will not work

Comment: It dont work. If i type:
 TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.Controls["tb2"];

There always means its "null"

Comment: I have MessageBoxes between the code and the name is identical.

Comment: can you type "tb2.visible = false;"

Comment: Yes.
Now i have the solution:

if (i < 9)
            {
                var textbox = Controls.Find("tb" + i, true).FirstOrDefault();
                if (textbox != null)
                {
                    textbox.Visible = true;
                }

                i++;
            }

Comment: Ok perfect, glad we could help

Comment: Thank you very much